# Meaning of 'f' in the os.F_OK mode in the os.access() method

Tags: python, module, operating-system

I am trying to understand what the individual letters stand for in the `os.access()` method modes. The others are clear (Capitalized letter for clarity):

`os.R_OK` - checks for Readability

`os.W_OK` - checks for Writability

`os.X_OK` - checks for eXecutability

but what does the F stand for in `os.F_OK`? Existence doesn't have an 'F' in it.

Comment: `E` already means error.

Comment: As a wild guess, `F` for `Found`/`Findable`?

Comment: Another wild guess, `F` for `File` as in file access OK?

Comment: It is almost definitely File

Answer (score 5):

from [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html):

> F_OK tests for the existence of the file.

may be F_OK for **F**ile existence **OK**.